Use of parameters in the subtitle of a quarto document
I can use the parameters in the title, but I could not find a way of using them in the subtitle. Is that possible?
A minimal example:
---
params:
  sp: "Iris"
title: Work on  species
subtitle: *`r params$sp`*
format: html
---

## Header

text

```{r}
plot(iris)
```

When it is run, it shows an error:
ERROR: YAMLError: unidentified alias "`r" at line 5, column 14:
    subtitle: *`r params$sp`*

It works fine if the same parameter is put in the title instead of the subtitle.

You should write your inline code in a string "" like this:
---
params:
  sp: "Iris"
title: Work on  species
subtitle: "*`r params$sp`*"
format: html
---

## Header

text

```{r}
plot(iris)
```

Output:

